# Why .mp3 file is getting '?' symbol next to it in res/raw in Android Studio?

Tags: android, audio

learning from Udacity and asked to make a new directory called raw and insert an audio file into it. Did the same but Android Studio asked to associate it with a file type and I couldn't see any file type related to sound so I cancelled it. Now audio file is getting question mark symbol next to it but the instructor of Udacity is getting some cd symbol next to her audio file.

Do answer cause I gotta know.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually recognizing. If you put any files in raw, its icon will be like question mark. But android studio can read it and do everything.